# Mass of Center of Homogeneous Surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was told to find the center of mass of a surface $z= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which is contained within the cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$.

I needed some hints on how to find the total mass of such surface. Do i need to parameterize the curve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parametrize the surface $S$, not the curve. You can proceed as follows:

Since the surface is part of the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, might as well use

$$
x=x, \quad y=y, \quad z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},
$$

with $x,y \in D:=\{(x,y)\; |\; x^2 +y^2 \le ax \}$.

Next, compute, $\|r_x \times r_y \|=\sqrt{2}$. You now have everything you need.

The mass is defined as the integral of the surface density $\rho(x,y,z)$ over $S$:

$$
m =\iint_S \rho(x,y,z) dS  =\iint_D \rho(x,y) \|r_x \times r_y \| dA.
$$

If you have a more precise expression of $\rho(x,y,z)$ you can finish evaluating the integral.